# Acumatica - Need Help in Updating Activities in Project Quotes Screen PM304500 through custom action

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom action on screen CR304000 - OpportunityMaint in the Quotes tab of the grid view that marks a field called IsPrimary in the CRQuote DAC as true for the current record in the Quotes view. These project Quotes are associated with the current opportunity as well as with a related PMQoute in the PMQuoteMaint BLC. The PMQuoteMaint BLC has a view called Activties that has all the CRActivities associated with the PMQuote. I created a custom field in the CRActivity called IsPrimary and added it to the Activities view in the PMQuoteMaint BLC grid.

My goal was to override the Action in the OpportunityMaint to update the IsPrimary field in CRActivity to true or false depending on what the Action in OpportunityMaint is toggling. However, my IsPrimary field in PMQuoteMaint is not toggling. My code attempts to get Current Quote OpportunityMain and then create a PMQuoteMaint graph and set the Current record. Then iterate though Activies view and set the IsPrimary field accordingly. Like I said, not having success because I'm not sure that my code is successfully retrieving the correct Activities.

There might be a better way to access CRActivity associated with a PMQuote, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated. Here is code:

````
    public virtual IEnumerable PrimaryQuote(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            foreach (CROpportunity opp in adapter.Get())
            {
                if (Quotes.Current?.IsPrimary != true)
                {
                    var selectExistingPrimary = new PXSelect<CRQuote, Where<CRQuote.quoteID, 
                    Equal<Required<CRQuote.quoteID>>>>(this);

                    CRQuote primary = selectExistingPrimary.Select(opp.DefQuoteID);
                    if (primary != null && primary.QuoteID != Quotes.Current.QuoteID && primary.Status == 
                    PM.PMQuoteStatusAttribute.Closed)
                    {
                        throw new PXException(PM.Messages.QuoteIsClosed, opp.OpportunityID, 
                        primary.QuoteNbr);
                    }


                    var quoteID = Quotes.Current.QuoteID;
                    var opportunityID = this.Opportunity.Current.OpportunityID;
                    this.Persist();
                    PXDatabase.Update<Standalone.CROpportunity>(
                    new PXDataFieldAssign<Standalone.CROpportunity.defQuoteID>(quoteID),
                    new PXDataFieldRestrict<Standalone.CROpportunity.opportunityID>(PXDbType.VarChar, 
                    255, opportunityID, PXComp.EQ)
                        );
                    this.Cancel.Press();
                    CROpportunity rec = this.Opportunity.Search<CROpportunity.opportunityID> 
                    (opportunityID);
                    yield return rec;
                }
                yield return opp;
          }


``` My OverRide


        public PXAction<CROpportunity> primaryQuote;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.MarkAsPrimary)]
        [PXButton]
        public virtual IEnumerable PrimaryQuote(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            // this is currently selected record in quotes grid
            var currQuoteNbr = Base.Quotes.Current.QuoteNbr;
            bool isPrimary2;
            foreach (CRQuote quote in Base.Quotes.Select())
            { 
                var quoteNbr = quote.QuoteNbr;
                if(quoteNbr.Trim() == currQuoteNbr.Trim())
                {
                    isPrimary2 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isPrimary2 = false;
                }
                PXTrace.WriteInformation(string.Format("Quote: {0} Value: 
                {1}",quoteNbr.ToString(),isPrimary2.ToString()));
                var PMQuoteMaintGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PMQuoteMaint>();
                PMQuoteMaintGraph.Quote.Current = PMQuoteMaintGraph.Quote.Search<PMQuote.quoteNbr> 
                (quoteNbr.Trim()); // this is the current quote

                foreach (CRActivity activity in PMQuoteMaintGraph.Activities.Select())
                 {

                    CRActivityExt itemExt = PXCache<CRActivity>.GetExtension<CRActivityExt>(activity);
                    itemExt.UsrPrimary = isPrimary2;
                    PMQuoteMaintGraph.Activities.Cache.Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);
                    PXDatabase.Update<CRActivity>(new PXDataFieldAssign<CRActivityExt.usrPrimary> 
                    (isPrimary2));
                  }
              }

            return Base.primaryQuote.Press(adapter);
         }
````